# Synergy: Dual Windows 7 PC & MacBook in between

Tags: windows, macos, synergy

I have a windows 7 PC set-up at work with my MacBook Pro in between the two monitors.

However, I am struggling to set Synergy up so that the mouse can be taken from monitor one, through the MacBook and onto monitor two.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the two monitors are attached to the Windows PC, then you can't do this.

Synergy lets you share the keyboard and mouse between desktops/workspaces, not screens. Two screens on the same computer are part of the same desktop.

So you could put the MacBook to the left or right of (or below) both monitors, but not in the middle.

Comment: Thanks for the post, I'll have to move it to either side, just ruins my set-up :(.

Thanks again.